# SWIFTUI Firestore single document mapping

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to use FirebaseFirestoreSwift to retrieve a document and pass it to a codable Struct. The documentation shows how to fetch documents, but I can t seem to make it work for a single one

here is my function :

```
unc fetchOwner() {
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("USERS").document(self.session.OwnerUid)
        .addSnapshotListener{ (snapUsers, err) in
        guard let allUsersDocs = snapUsers?.data() else {
            print("no docs")
            return
        }

            let users = allUsersDocs.compactMap({ (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> userProfile? in

                let user = QueryDocumentSnapshot.value as? userProfile
                self.session.currentUser = user!
                return user!
         })

     }
}
```

Comment: What does not work here and what did you expected should work?

Comment: You're dealing with a single document but your nomenclature suggests you're dealing with multiple documents—additionally confusing.

Comment: yes, it s true (just updated a piece of code where I fetch bunch of users (wich works)). I can easily retrieve and map a getDocument, but I can t seem to find the correct way to do it with a listener. The code compiles but crashes (error found nil). allUsersDocs prints corectly though ...

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you because we don't know what `userProfile` is. But you should really work on your naming conventions: you're dealing with a single document but the nomenclature says the opposite; `userProfile` is a type but you lowercase it; `QueryDocumentSnapshot` is a locally-scoped property but you uppercase it. I would consider this your number one priority right now. Spacing is also rather sloppy. You really should treat your source code with better care.

Comment: you are right ... totally